# How to control the tag order in the xml returned by a WCF [WebGet] marked method

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

My WCF service method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "decl/xml?s={s}")]
public Paradigm GetDeclensionXml(string s)
{
    return GetDeclension (s);
}
```

returns a custom object that has a bunch of string fields:

```
public class Paradigm
{
    public string genitive;
    public string dative;
    public string accusative;
    public string instrumental;
    public string prepositional;
}
```

that gets serialized to this XML:

```
<Paradigm xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MorpherWebDemo20.ws" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <accusative>росу</accusative>
    <dative>росе</dative>
    <genitive>росы</genitive>
    <instrumental>росой</instrumental>
    <prepositional>росе</prepositional>
</Paradigm>
```

I.e. the tags are automaticallly ordered by name.  I want them to appear in the order they are defined in my custon class.   Any ideas how to achieve that?

P.S.  The same happens if I change ResponseFormat to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate the class with `[DataContract]` and the members with `[DataMember]`, and you'll be able to use the `Order` property of this attribute to do what you want:

```
[DataContract]
public class Paradigm
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string genitive;
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string dative;
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string accusative;
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string instrumental;
    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string prepositional;
}
```